# How to pass connection parameters in the URL with OpenERP 7?

Tags: url, odoo

I am working with OpenERP 7. I want to know how can I log in the server by just passing connection parameters in the URL (db, login, password).

Any idea how can we do that ?

Comment: Do you mean log in from another system?

Comment: yes exactly, I want to connect to OpenERP server from another page, not throw the standard login page.